# What is $A-B\cup C$ in words?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm working through the set theory exercises in Apostol's Calculus Volume 1 and am having some trouble describing $A-(B\cup C)$ in words. What I'm thinking is: If $x\in A-(B\cup C)$ then $x$ is in $A$ and not in at least one of $B$ or $C$.

But to me this seems the same as $A-(B\cap C)$, because when I try describing this in words it's something like: If $x$ is in this set then $x$ is in $A$ and not in both $B$ and $C$. So $x$ is in $A$ and not in at least one of $B$ and $C$, which is the exact same qualitative description I gave of $A-(B\cup C)$.

But I know that obviously $A-(B\cap C)\ne A-(B\cup C)$ so where did I go wrong? Any help with qualitatively describing sets? Or is there a way of proving things about sets without needing these qualitative descriptions? (Apostol doesn't make this clear I'm afraid)

Comment: Your specific mistake is essentially that you need parentheses in your English phrase: for $A -(B\cup C)$, simply saying "not in at least one of B or C" is not the same as what you should say: "it is not the case that $x$ is in at least one of B or C." This latter phrase makes it clear that being in *either* B or C is not OK, and it must therefore be in *neither* of the two. Your phrase suggests that, as long as it's not in both, it's OK. This is the basically one of De Morgan's laws, but the spoken version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A picture is worth a thousand words.

[image: Venn Diagrams]

$A-(B \cup C)$ is everything in A that is not also in either B or C.

$A-(B \cap C)$ is everything in A that is not also in both B and in C.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've just solved a few more problems and it looks like I understand what is going on now. It turns out that my main problem was that I was thinking: "because $x\in B\cup C$ means $x$ is in at least one of $B$ or $C$, then $x\not\in B\cup C$ means $x$ is not in at least one of $B$ or $C$", which is kinda misleading be because it makes one think that $x$ is only not in at least one of $B$ or $C$, so it could be in $B$ and not in $C$ say - which is wrong! Rather, I should have realized that $x\not\in B\cup C$ means "$x$ is not in even at least one of $B$ or $C$". Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

$B \cup C$ is all elements that are in either $B$ or $C$.

So $A - (B \cup C)$ are all elements in $A$ but not in either $B$ or $C$, so in $A$ but in neither $B$ nor $C$.

$A - (B \cap C)$ would be all elements in $A$ but not in $B$ and $C$.

$(A - B) \cap C$ would be all elements that are in both $A$ and $C$ but not in $B$.

$(A - B) \cup C$ would be all elements that are in $C$, [pause for a short while] or in $A$ but not in $B$.

Comment: Thanks. so that answers the title. But how do you explain $A-B\cap C$? My main problem is: What is the difference between the qualitative explanation of $A-B\cap C$ nd $A-B\cup C$, as I seem to get the same thing when I try describing them in words. (See my post)

Comment: I don't know the order of operation for set operations. Do you mean $(A-B) \cup C$ or $A-(B\cup C)$?

Comment: @user45220 English is flimsy as you maybe can tell. $A \setminus (B\cap C)$ is akin to saying "all elements in $A$ excluding those that are shared by both $B$ and $C$" where as  $A \setminus (B\cup C)$ would be "all elements in $A$ excluding those that are in $B$ or $C$".

Comment: @StevenGregory: Sorry, I meant the second one: $A-(B\cup C)$.

Comment: I included the other forms as well.